# After Composer update laravel assets url not comes with public

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.6

in my Laravel 5.6 project i have a image URL

```
<img alt="بيتي فور" src="http://localhost/alhazim_working/public/assets/images/spinner.gif" data-src="http://localhost/alhazim_working/public/uploads/products/images/thumbnails/Petit four_2_3.png">
```

After run the composer update the url is not comes with public and image is not loading

```
<img alt="بيتي فور" src="http://localhost/alhazim_working/assets/images/spinner.gif" data-src="http://localhost/alhazim_working/uploads/products/images/thumbnails/Petit four_2_3.png">
```

similarly all the Css, Js and other images not working without public in url

also i run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear` and generate key after composer update

and my folder structure is 
[image]

also i run project without artisan commant

Comment: Please show your folder structure of the laravel project. Whats the `alhazim_working` folder? And where is it?

Comment: please see the screenshop of file structure

Answer (score 3):

Laravel has a `public` folder which is the base folder for all requests. So if an image is in there you don't need to enter `public` in the url.

If your assets folder is in the `public` folder of laravel your url has to be like this:

```
http://localhost/assets/images/spinner.gif
```

instead of:

```
http://localhost/alhazim_working/public/assets/images/spinner.gif
```

Change it and your images will be displayed.

Comment: my url  works only when url contain public, i need to work it without public

Comment: Do you have a public inside of the public folder? If not your server is configured wrong. Please check the server configurations in the laravel docs.